# get value DIV in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to get DIV contents in PHP to submit a form.

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

In my search, I was advised to use `<input type="hidden"` but I do not know how to do.

Comment: Please elaborate **"recover"**

Comment: what you want share your code and explain your question

Comment: sorry, GET (google translation :p)

Comment: That still doesn’t make this an understandable question. Div elements do not have a “value”. You will need to explain what you actually want to achieve here in more, proper detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you are obtaining the HTML as a string, or even if its a remote web page, you will need a HTML parser. There are lots of these for PHP and the question has already been asked and answered. [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

If you are looking to do this on click or some other page event when a user does something, you need to use javascript instead of PHP. PHP is a server side language and cant be used to access elements in the users web browser, you need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an input field to show a value (perhaps because you don't want the user to modify it or for styling reasons). You can display it in a div, and pass the value with the form submission by duplicating the value in a hidden input positioned inside your form.  The div may be inside or outside your form.

```
<div id="user">Jaber</div>
<form>
    ... any other form fields
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="Jaber">
    ... submit button
</form>
```